# Don't wait till javascript ends function

Tags: javascript, ajax, wait

I am working with **onkeydown** events in order to get the written value *(in a textarea)*, process it on a PHP file *(passing it by Ajax post)* and showing the result in an external div...
The problem is that each time I press the key, I can't continue writing till Ajax does its task. How can I make it possible to keep writing even if the text hasn't been processed yet?

**---EDIT---**

```
function fromWCtoHTML(source){
 var act = new Date();
 http[act] = createRequestObject();
 http[act].open('post', '/php/fromWCtoHTML.php',false);
 http[act].setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded',false);
 http[act].send("source=" + source);
 document.getElementById('AJAXWCtoHTML').innerHTML=http[act].responseText;
}
```

Comment: can we see your ajax code, it seems likley you have `async: false`, this would make it a synchronous call instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http[act].open('post', '/php/fromWCtoHTML.php',false);`

The 3rd parameter[`false`] is causing your request to be synchronous.
Change it to `true` or do not include it.

**EDIT** Response for the comment stating that http[act].responseText is blank.

Add an `onreadystate` event handler. Try the following code

```
function fromWCtoHTML(source){
 var act = new Date();
 http[act] = createRequestObject();
 http[act].open('post', '/php/fromWCtoHTML.php');
 http[act].setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded',false);
 http[act].send("source=" + source);
  http[act].onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (http[act].readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById('AJAXWCtoHTML').innerHTML=http[act].responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but... If I do so then the `http[act].responseText` reponse is blank.

Comment: Modern browsers (incl. IE > IE6) also accept **this** instead of `http[act]` in the `onreadystatechange`-Event

Answer (score 5):

You have set `async` to false:

```
http[act].open('post', '/php/fromWCtoHTML.php',false);
                                               ^^^^^^
```

This makes it blocking. Don't do that.

Be aware, however, that most people can type characters faster then HTTP requests can be made and responses received, so sending a request with every key press isn't a good idea.

Comment: If I change it to true, it gives no result (blank txtReponse). Considering that I want a real-time preview in an external div of what the user is writing, how else could I do it?

Comment: It gives no response because you are reading the response immediately instead of waiting for it to come back. You need a readyStateChange handler. Any Ajax tutorial should explain that. http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

Comment: Thank you, now it is working. What would be a better way to do the same thing without sending a request every keypress?

Comment: Track requests you make so you never have more than one in flight. Send a new one if you have none in flight when a key is pressed or when a request returns and a key was pressed since the last one was sent.

Comment: The best way would be to add a timer (e.g. a second, the bigger this number the more time the user has between keypress) as soon as the user starts typing, once the timer elapses then run the ajax function, everytime the user types another key reset the timer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onreadystatechange-Event from XMLHttpRequest , just put `document.getElementById('AJAXWCtoHTML').innerHTML=http[act].responseText;`
 in an anonymous function and set the event-handler.